# Keep-Alive not working for some files

Tags: magento-1.9, htaccess

On PageSpeed I am getting this : Enable Keep-Alive

```
https://www.example.com/
https://www.example.com/skin/frontend/example/retail/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0
https://www.example.com/skin/frontend/example/retail/fonts/gotham-bold-webfont.woff2
https://www.example.com/skin/frontend/example/retail/fonts/gotham-book-webfont.woff2
https://www.example.com/skin/frontend/example/retail/fonts/gotham-medium-webfont.woff2
```

**My htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>


############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip




    # Insert filter on all content
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
#    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript
   # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-woff
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-woff2
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-woff
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-woff
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
   # SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary


</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
```

How to resolve this ?

Comment: Did you check this page for help: https://varvy.com/pagespeed/keep-alive.html? Also, you could check your site here: https://www.giftofspeed.com/enable-keep-alive/

Comment: @ArjenMiedema yes i have checked

Comment: did the page return that it was enabled? If so, did you also check if the files that show up on PageSpeed have a filetype listed in your htaccess file?

Comment: It's showing enable but, But I am getting errors for few files only'

Comment: Okay. And the filetypes you added, do they include the actual font types? No typos or anything?

Comment: Yes, they included.